# how to block "microsoft edge webview2 runtime" auto updates

Tags: windows, auto-update, webview2

I have a program that installs "microsoft edge webview2 runtime" for proper functionality.
If i uninstall it, program stop working.

The problem is: sometimes "microsoft edge webview2 runtime" updates it self and some times it crushed while PC.

The question is: how to block auto updates for this runtime?

Answer (score 0):

There is one install of the WebView2 Runtime on an end user's machine that is used by all WebView2 apps. Blocking updates to the WebView2 Runtime means all apps are impacted and all apps stop receiving fixes for crashes and bugs, new features, and security fixes and so is not recommended.

If you see an issue with the WebView2 Runtime please let us know in the [WebView2 Feedback project](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues) so we can help resolve the issue.

Comment: Hello! i believe that there are already was a detailed feedback by user here: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1223   but still no fix. I think that its a good idea to give users option to update manually. if i remove folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate  will it stop autoupdates?

Comment: "Dont do it, because I said so". Thanks, but no thanks.